# Github: Select required status checks not working for Github actions

Tags: github, github-actions

I have set up some Github actions workflows in my repo and want to require some of them to pass before a PR can be merged into the main branch. Therefore I selected these actions in branch protection rules, but these do not seem to apply. Only the styleci and appveyor checks are marked as required. All actions are not.

Any ideas what I am missing?

[Example PR](https://github.com/TYPO3-Console/TYPO3-Console/pull/993)
[Screenshot from settings](https://twitter.com/helhum/status/1397197422313496580)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like Github does support emojis in job names, but does not support matching jobs as required, when there are emojis in job names. Removing the emojis makes the jobs look less nice, but makes the branch protection rules work.